# jsonpath как отобрать только словари(в списке) с длиной равной =3

Tags: python, json, jsonpath

Использую бибилиотеку для парсинга внутри json массива: jsonpath.
Не подскажите как отфильтровать в данном списке только те словари где длина этого словаря равна =3 либо же содержит только ключи "C", "G", "T" ???

```
[
  {
    "C": 1.76,
    "G": 1,
    "T": 1
  },
  {
    "C": 1.995,
    "G": 1,
    "T": 3
  },
  {
    "C": 1.868,
    "CE": 1,
    "G": 2,
    "P": -1.5,
    "T": 7
  },
  {
    "C": 1.792,
    "CE": 1,
    "G": 2,
    "P": 1.5,
    "T": 8
  },
  {
    "C": 1.9,
    "CE": 1,
    "G": 17,
    "P": 76.5,
    "T": 9
  },
  {
    "C": 1.82,
    "CE": 1,
    "G": 17,
    "P": 76.5,
    "T": 10
  },
  {
    "C": 1.84,
    "CE": 1,
    "G": 15,
    "P": 39.5,
    "T": 11
  },
  {
    "C": 1.82,
    "CE": 1,
    "G": 15,
    "P": 39.5,
    "T": 12
  },
  {
    "C": 1.832,
    "CE": 1,
    "G": 62,
    "P": 38.5,
    "T": 13
  },
  {
    "C": 1.89,
    "CE": 1,
    "G": 62,
    "P": 38.5,
    "T": 14
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел для себя такой вариант: 
задал фильтр на наличие ключа "C" и одновременно отсутствие ключа "P"

### array[?(@.C && !@.P)]

{
"C": 1.76,
"G": 1,
"T": 1
},
{
"C": 1.995,
"G": 1,
"T": 3
}

Если есть другие варианты, напишите :)

Answer (score 1):

Итак определим входные данные

```py
test_list = [
  {
    "C": 1.76,
    "G": 1,
    "T": 1
  },
  {
    "C": 1.995,
    "G": 1,
    "T": 3
  },
  {
    "C": 1.868,
    "CE": 1,
    "G": 2,
    "P": -1.5,
    "T": 7
  },
  {
    "C": 1.792,
    "CE": 1,
    "G": 2,
    "P": 1.5,
    "T": 8
  },
  {
    "C": 1.9,
    "CE": 1,
    "G": 17,
    "P": 76.5,
    "T": 9
  },
  {
    "C": 1.82,
    "CE": 1,
    "G": 17,
    "P": 76.5,
    "T": 10
  },
  {
    "C": 1.84,
    "CE": 1,
    "G": 15,
    "P": 39.5,
    "T": 11
  },
  {
    "C": 1.82,
    "CE": 1,
    "G": 15,
    "P": 39.5,
    "T": 12
  },
  {
    "C": 1.832,
    "CE": 1,
    "G": 62,
    "P": 38.5,
    "T": 13
  },
  {
    "C": 1.89,
    "CE": 1,
    "G": 62,
    "P": 38.5,
    "T": 14
  }
]
```

Если искать по длине словаря то можно вот так:

```py
result_list = []
for i in test_list:
    if len(i) == 3:
        result_list.append(i)

print(result_list)

# OUT
# [{'C': 1.76, 'G': 1, 'T': 1}, {'C': 1.995, 'G': 1, 'T': 3}]
```

Если по значениям ключей, то можно использовать тип данных `set` - неупорядоченный набор уникальных значений. Ключи словаря уникальны, поэтому нам нужно просто сравнить с допустимыми значениями ключей. Для этого определим переменную `allowed_keys` с тем набором ключей, которые хотим получить на выходе.

```py
allowed_keys = {"C", "G", "T"}
result_list2 = []
for i in test_list:
    if allowed_keys == set(i.keys()):
        result_list2.append(i)

print(result_list2)

# OUT
# [{'C': 1.76, 'G': 1, 'T': 1}, {'C': 1.995, 'G': 1, 'T': 3}]
```

Логика для последнего такая: если словарь содержит только ключи C, G, и T, только в таком наборе, то мы добавляем в список. Если словарь содержит другие ключи, или эти ключи, но в наборе есть только два/один из них, или любой другой вариант, то мы его в список не добавляем.